Connecting to ArangoDB in a Kubernetes cluster
I'm trying to connect to an ArangoDB server running in a Kubernetes cluster from a kotlin program running in kubernetes as well. The connection attempt blocks, and I don't get any sort of exception or error in the client's logs.
Here's how I'm trying to connect:
    private val arangoDb =
        ArangoDB
            .Builder()
            .serde(
                JacksonSerde.of(ContentType.JSON).apply {
                    configure {
                        it
                            .registerModule(kotlinModule())
                            .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
                    }
                },
            ).user(arangoDbUser)
            .password(arangoDbPass)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_JSON)
            .useSsl(true)
            .sslContext(SSLContext.getDefault())
            .host(arangoDbHost, arangoDbPort)
            .build()
            .db(arangoDbConfig.database)


I am able to connect with wget using the same host and port from a shell on the client's kubernetes pod. I get the expected index.html file. I also tried bypassing the ArangoDB client using java.net.http.HttpRequest:
        val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI("https://$arangoDbHost:$arangoDbPort/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html#login"))
            .GET()
            .build()
        val response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())

It also blocks with no exception or error.
I know these are blocking, because the logging lines before them fire, but the ones after do not.
